# MVC Viewbag shows System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show my Viewbag.studentFaculty in View

but when i wrote @Viewbag.studentFaculty

i got the value like this   **System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Faculty_D453027D6C8963B9EE27305AED88670DD8233614**

My Code

```
int FGD = db.Students.Where(stu => stu.StudentID == id).Select(f => f.Student_FGD_FK).FirstOrDefault();
Faculty stufac= db.FacultyGovermentDepartments.Where(f => f.FGD_ID == FGD).Select(fac => fac.Faculty).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.StudentFaculty = stufac;
```

Comment: Show how you assign he value on the controller

Comment: Edit your question (and then delete the comment)

Comment: `Faculty` is a complex object, so it needs to `@Viewbag.studentFaculty.SomeProperty`

Comment: studentFaculty is My property which i worte it from my mind

Comment: Thanks for helping i understand what you mean thanksssssssss

Answer (score 1):

You could store it in a variable:

```
var faculty = (Faculty)ViewBag.StudentFaculty
```